# Which function is called after update any field of user from any where of the site

Tags: users

I have a membership site I want to call a function when any fields of user will update from any where of site.

I was used this function but it is not Running:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_id = $current_user->ID;
 function update_extra_profile_fields($user_id) {
     if ( current_user_can('edit_user',$user_id) )
         myfunction();
 }
```

Please help me

Comment: You need to hook your function. This might guide you in right direction https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/profile_update

Comment: Can you please explain your requirment in details

Answer (score 0):

the action `update_user_meta` is done before the value is saved in database

you can try this code

```
add_action("update_user_meta", function ($meta_id, $user_id, $meta_key, $_meta_value) {


    if (current_user_can('edit_user', $user_id)) {

        // do something


    }


});
```

Comment: The function will call after any field update not a specific meta field.

Comment: .yes it's that.

Answer (score 0):

```
// this action run when the your user meta updated.
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'your_custom_function_name' );

// this action run when the other user meta updated.
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'your_custom_function_name' );
```

Comment: Mr Ajay, try adding a bit more content here.  This is the right tag but the question is not actually answered by what you've submitted.

Comment: Hello Mr Ajay i was try your code but it is not working according to my requirment